# System.ObjectDisposedException: "Доступ к ликвидированному объекту невозможен. Почему?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SlavaForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        Form3 с = new Form3();
        Form4 k = new Form4();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            f.Show();
            
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            с.Show();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Location = new Point(100, 500);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            k.Show();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            f.Close();
            с.Close();
            k.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Я вызвываю 3 формы с 3 гифками, потом их закрываю, но при повторном открытии выдается ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form.Close()` - это синоним `Dispose()`. Используйте `Hide()`.

Comment: Cпасибо большое

Comment: @Slava Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.